# Capturing Screen: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#

I've written a small program that scans the screen for a certain color. I am having problems with capturing the screen though. It works for a while but eventually it crashes with:[this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4gmE.png). I've tried changing the variables from local to global but I got the same error. Here is my method:

```
    static IntPtr hSrcDc;
    static IntPtr hDc;
    static Bitmap screenCopy;

    static Bitmap Capture(Rectangle r)
    {
        screenCopy = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenCopy))
        {
            using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                hSrcDc = gsrc.GetHdc();
                hDc = gdest.GetHdc();
                BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, r.Width, r.Height, hSrcDc, r.X, r.Y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                gdest.ReleaseHdc();
                gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
            }
        }
        return screenCopy;
    }
```

Comment: Do you properly dispose of your `screenCopy` after using it?   Actually, why is it a **static variable**?  What happens to the old one when you overwrite it?

Comment: Agreed...you might need: `if (sourceCopy != null) { sourceCopy.Dispose(); }` if you don't need that old screenshot.  Or just get rid of all the static variables and make them local.  It's unclear how they are being used, however.  Also, how often are you taking screenshots?

Comment: Thank you, I changed some stuff around and added a screenCopy.Dispose(). Now it works!